# R - Regular Expression error (PCRE Version)

Tags: r, pcre

I'm trying to use `koRpus` in R to do lemmatization on a Linux server running RHEL6.  Last week when I had MRO (Microsoft R Open) 3.2.3 installed the code below worked great:

```
library(koRpus)
lw = c("dancing","flying","flew")
res = treetag(lw,treetagger="manual",format="obj",TT.tknz = F, lang="en",
        TT.options=list(path="/usr/local/bin/TreeTagger",preset="en"))
```

Now that I'm running MRO 3.3.0 though I get the following error:

```
Error in grepl("(^\\p{P}*\\p{L}\\p{M}*\\.)", tkn, perl = TRUE) :
  invalid regular expression '(^\p{P}*\p{L}\p{M}*\.)'
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl("(^\\p{P}*\\p{L}\\p{M}*\\.)", tkn, perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
        'support for \P, \p, and \X has not been compiled'
        at 'p{P}*\p{L}\p{M}*\.)'
```

OK, so that means my PCRE needs to be recompiled with unicode support.  In fact when I run the code below I see that's the exact issue.  I also see that I'm running version 8.37.

```
pcre_config()
#>         UTF-8 Unicode properties                JIT
#>          TRUE              FALSE              FALSE

extSoftVersion()
#>                 zlib                     bzlib                        xz
#>              "1.2.8"      "1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010"                   "5.2.2"
#>                 PCRE                       ICU                       TRE
#>    "8.37 2015-04-28"                    "57.1" "TRE 0.8.0 R_fixes (BSD)"
#>                iconv
#>         "glibc 2.12"
```

Now, I went ahead and installed 8.39 and with (hopefully) the right flags set.

```
./configure --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
make
make install
```

So now when I run `pcretest -C` I get

```
PCRE version 8.39 2016-06-14
Compiled with
  8-bit support
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Parentheses nest limit = 250
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

But when I launch R again my `pcre_config()` yields identical results, the `treetag` call fails identically and `extSoftVersion()` still reports 8.37.

**What do I need to do for R to start using the new PCRE version?**

Deeper and deeper...
R apparently no longer ships with PCRE (per https://mran.microsoft.com/news/#r330) as of 3.3.0 so it (supposedly) relies on the system PCRE installation.  I went through the server and removed every PCRE file identifiable (complete uninstallation) and R still reports `PCRE 8.37 2015-04-28` which suggests the MRO 3.3.0 for RHEL 6 includes PCRE despite claiming otherwise.  Additionally, the `grepl` command still fails with the error too, so it's not just an issue with `extSoftVersion`.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall 8.37 with your compilation options *(the flags)*?

Comment: Just did - no change to `pcre_config()` results.

Comment: Not sure if its still relevant, but did you try to reinstall R after reinstalling pcre? We had a pcre jit compilation issue on our SLES system and what helped was to 1. uninstall/delete current R version 2. install pcre from source 3. install R again.