# R errors because of PCRE configuration, unicode properties

Tags: r, regex, unicode, pcre, tm

I am using the removeWords and tm_map() functions in the tm package in order to parse some text data. My understanding is that it simply uses Perl regular expressions through gsub() to complete the task.

However, when I run my code, I get a strange error. I am using R 3.3.2.

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores=1)
```

And I get...

```
Error in gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  : 
  invalid regular expression '(*UCP)\b(yourselves|yourself|yours|your|you've|you're|you'll|you'd|you|wouldn't|would|won't|with|why's|why|whom|who's|who|while|which|where's|where|when's|when|what's|what|weren't|were|we've|we're|we'll|we'd|we|wasn't|was|very|up|until|under|too|to|through|those|this|they've|they're|they'll|they'd|they|these|there's|there|then|themselves|them|theirs|their|the|that's|that|than|such|some|so|shouldn't|should|she's|she'll|she'd|she|shan't|same|own|over|out|ourselves|ours|our|ought|other|or|only|once|on|off|of|not|nor|no|myself|my|mustn't|most|more|me|let's|itself|its|it's|it|isn't|is|into|in|if|i've|i'm|i'll|i'd|i|how's|how|his|himself|him|herself|hers|here's|here|her|he's|he'll|he'd|he|having|haven't|have|hasn't|has|hadn't|had|further|from|for|few|each|during|down|don't|doing|doesn't|does|do|didn't|did|couldn't|could|cannot|can't|by|but|both|between|below|being|before|been|because|be|at|as|aren't|are|any|and|an|am|all|against|again|after|above|about|a
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
    'this version of PCRE is not compiled with Unicode property support'
    at '(*UCP)\b(yourselves|yourself|yours|your|you've|you're|you'll|you'd|you|wouldn't|would|won't|with|why's|why|whom|who's|who|while|which|where's|where|when's|when|what's|what|weren't|were|we've|we're|we'll|we'd|we|wasn't|was|very|up|until|under|too|to|through|those|this|they've|they're|they'll|they'd|they|these|there's|there|then|themselves|them|theirs|their|the|that's|that|than|such|some|so|shouldn't|should|she's|she'll|she'd|she|shan't|same|own|over|out|ourselves|ours|our|ought|other|or|only|once|on|off|of|not|nor|no|myself|my|mustn't|most|more|me|let's|itself|its|it's|it|isn't|is|into|in|if|i've|i'm|i'll|i'd|i|how's|how|his|himself|him|herself|hers|here's|here|her|he's|he'll|he'd|he|having|haven't|have|hasn't|has|hadn't|had|further|from|for|few|each|during|down|don't|doing|doesn't|does|do|didn't|did|couldn't|could|cannot|can't|by|but|both|between|below|being|before|been|because|be| [... truncated]
```

As I understand it, the important part is "this version of PCRE is not compiled with Unicode property support." Any ideas on how to address this? I ran pcre_config() in R and got the following:

```
     UTF-8 Unicode properties                JIT 
      TRUE              FALSE              FALSE
```

And outside of R, I ran pcretest -C and got the following:

```
PCRE version 7.8 2008-09-05
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A [related thread with no answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796564/r-regular-expression-error-pcre-version).

Comment: I saw...I was hoping for better luck somehow with a different question.

Comment: @RickyB You may want to include the results of `sessionInfo()`.  This may or may not be a platform dependent issue.

Comment: A couple of more things, having sample input data (as simple as possible) to reproduce the error would be a good thing to add to your question.  The other is, have you contacted the maintainer of this package ?  You can find the contact info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) at CRAN.

Comment: It may be that your PCRE library is too old (7.8). It should be at least 8.32, see R-admin manual. If upgrading does not help, this question might be worth asking on R-help mailing list, but in either case you'll need a minimal reproducible example and information about your platform (at least sessionInfo() output).

Answer (score 1):

RickyB

I faced the same problem while was trying to create word cloud tool. For some reason "stopwords" function does not work properly.

I found a solution here:
[Manual removal of stopwords](https://rpubs.com/irJERAD/TrumpWordCloud)

Here are my codes after making few changes to the codes in the above link:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores=1)
```

Manually removing stopwords:

```
r <- read.table(fill=TRUE, url("http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/"))
stopWords <- r
vstop <- as.vector(stopWords)
stpWrd <- stopwords("SMART")
text <- unlist(text)[!(unlist(text) %in% stpWrd)]
```

I hope it helps.